# What are the aerodynamic differences between the nose designs of the CSeries and the Boeing 737?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, nose, airbus-a220

The Bombardier CSeries and the Boeing 737 are two aircraft in the same class. Their nose shapes are very different from each other though as can be seen in these two images. What are the major aerodynamic differences between these two nose designs?

CSeries:
[image: CSeries]
Image [Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Swiss-International-Air/Bombardier-CSeries-CS100/2718651/L/)

Boeing 737:
[image: Boeing 737]
Image [Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Delta-Air-Lines/Boeing-737-732/1850974/M/)

---

**Note:** [This](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12915/why-do-boeing-and-airbus-have-distinctively-different-nose-designs) question and answer set don't really answer my question here because it talks about a generic nose form of aircraft made by Boeing and Airbus. I am looking for specific aerodynamic differences between *nose cone shapes on specific models of Boeing and Bombardier aircraft*. The Airbus part of that question cannot answer the Bombardier part of this question.

That question also does not talk about specific model as it says at the bottom:

> This image is only an example and my question is not about any specific model.

I want the specifics for the nose cone shapes of Boeing 737 and the Bombardier CSeries, not specifics on the aircraft themselves. *This is more like asking for for the aerodynamic difference, for example, between a blunt nose and an ogive nose* than something to do with aircraft corporations.

Comment: I'm guessing that a lot of the issue here is just age. The 737 design is literally 45 years older than the C-Series. The nose of the 737 was probably designed to house very large radar equipment. On top of that advances in numerical analysis and computer assisted design allow for much better analysis of aerodynamics.

Comment: @Simon This is between Bombardier and Boeing, so it is not anything close.

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer factually. The only way to get an answer is to get a Boeing engineer and a Bombardier engineer in the same room to discuss the reasons for going with one over the other. Aside from that any answer you get is probably pure speculation or opinion.

Comment: @RonBeyer Are there any specifics on what the nose designs on these two aircraft are called? It might help more.

Comment: Did you read the top answer to the question? It exactly answers your question.  If you feel it does not, then please edit your question to be more explicit.

Comment: It's technology. The Boeing 737 nose flew first in 1957 (as the Boeing 707 nose, no less) and uses flat glass panes - curved ones were not possible back then. The Bombardier C-Series had its first flight 55 years later and uses curved window panes which follow the contour of the forward fuselage.